# Linearize the generated pdf from BIRT

Tags: pdf, birt, linearization

I have a problem in generating the pdf report in BIRT.

When I generate the pdf report, it is downloaded in browser. When i checked the properties of the generated pdf(File  -> Properties) . Fast Web View is assigned to No. It should be Yes. It creates some problem.

Is there any workaround for this fast web view (linearize) in BIRT.

can anyone faced this type of issue?

Kindly check the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

BIRT doesn't support this, and I think iText doesn't support this.

But if you have any other library to create a linearized PDF, you could take the PDF generated by BIRT, linearize it using your library and then serve the linearized PDF to the client.

Comment: Is there any java libraries available for linearize the pdf file? If yes kindly share any link or reference.Thanks

Comment: Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit will linearize PDFs (http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdfjavatoolkit/). Disclaimer, I work for Datalogics and it is not a free solution.